# How to get data of another table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table 1: kpi_detail column[redValue, amberValue, greenValue]
Table 2: data_detail 


$sql= "SELECT id,kpi_code,kpi_name,result_data,target, count_date, SUM(result_data) AS total_data, assign FROM data_detail GROUP BY kpi_code";

Expected table columns results:
id| kpi_code | kpi_name | result_data | target | count_date | total_data | assign | redValue | amberValue | greenValue |
```

It looks like the `GROUP BY` is giving me trouble on joining two tables. How do I get the 3 columns of table1 `kpi_detail`? Join the 3 columns from table 2 to table 1

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question mentions two tables, but your query only references one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think it's [a repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58887634/problem-to-get-value-of-variable-to-mysql-query), or am I wrong?

Comment: I guess it's a "figure it out yourself pal" then. [I feel "snobbed".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893128/how-to-get-data-of-another-table-in-mysql#comment104051449_58893128) ^

Answer (score 0):

You have "bare" columns in the `GROUP BY`.  You should be using aggregation functions for all the columns not in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MAX(id), kpi_code, MAX(kpi_name), MAX(result_data),
       MAX(target), MAX(count_date), SUM(result_data) AS total_data,
       MAX(assign)
FROM data_detail
GROUP BY kpi_code
```